# Convert a string into 2D Array in python

Tags: python, arrays

I take an image from webcam in python, it is an array so I convert it to string using `numpy.array_str()`, now after doing that I need to convert that string back to an array as efficiently as possible.
I have already tried it using for statements but it takes around half a second, which is just too slow for my use-case. I have even searched the web for numpy's built-in function to do the task but did not find any solution.

Comment: "it is a array so I convert it to string" - why? If you want to save it to a file, use `numpy.save` (binary) or [`numpy.savetxt`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) (human readable) instead

Comment: i wanted it to transfer over sockets

Comment: In this case, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26377023/send-a-multidimensional-numpy-array-over-a-socket and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30167538/convert-a-numpy-ndarray-to-stringor-bytes-and-convert-it-back-to-numpy-ndarray

Answer (score 1):

The numpy.array_str() function returns a string with a whitespace separator between the array elements as https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_str.html

To convert it back to an array, you can use str.split() without specifying the delimiter because it considers whitespace as default.